# Drupal 8 module getting "$entity" argument error with hook_entity_presave

Tags: module, hook, drupal-8

I am trying to create a module in Drupal 8 (8.9.11) and this module uses the function hook_entity_presave in order to update a node / entity programmatically. I've tried the answers from https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223346/hook-entity-presave-doesnt-work, I was able to add those in my code.
Here is my routing.yml (sno.routing.yml):

```
sno.content:
  path: /node/add/issuances
  defaults:
    _controller: Drupal\sno\Controller\SnoController::sno_entity_presave
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Here is my Controller (src/Controller/SnoController.php):

```
namespace Drupal\sno\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

class SnoController {
    public function sno_entity_presave(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
      if ($entity->getEntityType()->id() == 'issuances') {
     $entity->set('field_s', ', s. ');
    //CAUTION : Do not save here, because it's automatic.
    
    }   
}
}
```

When I got into adding a content of content type issuance (/node/add/issuances), I am getting the error below:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

RuntimeException: Controller "Drupal\sno\Controller\SnoController::sno_entity_presave()" requires that you provide a value for the "$entity" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one. in Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ArgumentResolver->getArguments() (line 78 of /var/www/senate-library/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Controller/ArgumentResolver.php).
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are attempting to utilise the [hook_entity_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/9.1.x) hook, then you should move it to a `sno.module` as per their design.

The `$entity` object will then automatically resolve to an instance of `Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface`, which wouldn't occur when doing it via a Controller method.

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains sno.module.
 */

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_entity_presave().
 */
function sno_entity_presave(EntityInterface $entity) {
  // Do stuff.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing this one up baikho! In fact, my first iteration of my code was only having sno.info.yml and sno.module but I was not getting what I wanted. But now, trying it out again with just the bare codes like yours I am now able to insert/update that text into one  of my fields. Previously there is a namespace in my code, Could that be the reason why? I also had some use statements like use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityChangedInterface; but I think this does not matter. But anyway,  the code is already working and I'm happy with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to take a look to [Drupal hooks](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/understanding-hooks) to know how it works.

To use a `hook`, you shouldn't create a route but just implement it on `.module` file.
Your hook function will be automatically invoked in the Drupal core process (in your case, it is entity saving flow).

Now you should move `sno_entity_presave()` function to `sno.module` then it will work.